# Error 1130 in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1130

when i am trying to log on mysql using my ip address i am getting error 1130 qht can i do for this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your client IP is not allowed to connect to this server, you must add it to allowed client account 
For exemple, assuming you add an user account having all rights in one database :

```
grant all on db.* to 'username'@'192.168.0.1';
```

Where db is database name, username  the username , and your clients IP is 192.168.0.1

See [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html) for details of user account creation

Comment: this is SQL query to run on server with an account with enough privileges to do grant queries on the table

Answer (score 54):

On your server run mysql from command line:

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost -P 3306
```

Then run this command in mysql shell:

```
>use mysql
>GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';
>FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Have a nice time.

Comment: This one should be the best answer imo. Nice thing, this "%" :)

Comment: Except it is a bad advice security-wise. One should always use the most precise rule, here specifying the client IP address as a host or its NAT public IP, or a rule matching his DHCP subnet ('192.168.1.%" for example)

Comment: It has been fixed my issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: osx's default mysql pkg was causing me a lot of trouble, this solves it.

Comment: May 2018. Still applicable. Thank you. You may want to update the command due to `Warning (Code 1287): Using GRANT statement to modify existing user's properties other than privileges is deprecated and will be removed in future release. Use ALTER USER statement for this operation.`

Answer (score 0):

On your server run mysql from command line:

mysql -u root -p -h localhost -P 3306
Then run this command in mysql shell:

> use mysql
>
> GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
>
> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Perfect! great steps and resolve the error
Failure loading users data from backend [xx.xx.xx.x:3306] for service [Write Failover]. MySQL error 1130, Host

'xx.xx.xx.x' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server