# #1130 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Tags: linux

#1130 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

im getting this error while my trying to log in to phpmyadmin through virtualmin ( virtualmin has given me credentials to log in to phpmyadmin , but when i enter those it shows the above error )

please help !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 1130 in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857446/error-1130-in-mysql)

Comment: what should i do ?

Comment: check credentials and access using telnet or similar

Comment: Thankyou but i'm not able to get you !!

Comment: granting privileges wont help ??