# some requests return SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server on production server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sqlexception

I am handling a Laravel app on a shared host, everything is running fine , however, Some pages return

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to
>   this MySQL server

randomly in some requests. However, most of the time everything works just fine

Here are understand.io logs for this error:
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you need to check table level permissions in MySQL... [`SHOW GRANTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-grants.html) might be a good place to start.

Comment: @ficuscr All privileges are granted for database users instead of the DROP privilege

Comment: And from where? Anywhere? 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost? An IP? a range? I think the error is clear. Just have to figure out why. The inconsistency suggested it might be some tables.

Comment: Actually nothing in common, however, I didn't check IPs. I'll check that right back. 

Regarding tables, no specific tables are causing the error as this error happened almost once on every route.

Comment: I can't find a common IP range but, I think it's because the company is using a shared host and the SQL Server can go down sometimes as this happens on the development server only when the SQL server is shut down

Comment: That could explain the "Can't connect to MySQL server..." I guess. Assumed the application and database were on a single, common server... Would still be interested in seeing output from `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'someuser'@'localhost';` Error 1130 is pretty clear. Fix is [as stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857446/error-1130-in-mysql).

Comment: User given access to phpMyAdmin by hosting provider is not the same as the user accessing via the application (this can't be changed and phpMyAdmin user can't be used for application) also this user is not allowed to execute SHOW GRANTS command

Answer (score 0):

change your `.env` file in `DB_HOST` set **mysql**:

```
DB_HOST=mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, randomly at some requests, also on shared hosting.

What solved it for me was changing `DB_HOST` in the `.env` file from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`.