# "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host '127.0.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server" in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I want to run a project in live with CPanel.

But getting error while browsing the site

> "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host '127.0.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server"

I have created database, username and password in phpMyAdmin and use those in `.env` file.

**.env** file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=shirinc1_sencare
DB_USERNAME=shirinc1_sencare
DB_PASSWORD=shirinc1_sencare
```

also change in `config/database.php`

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'shirinc1_sencare'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'shirinc1_sencare'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'shirinc1_sencare'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

But still getting this error. Can't find the solution yet.

Anybody Help Please ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857446/error-1130-in-mysql

Comment: do you grant that user all privileges ?

Comment: @Md.Amirozzaman.....yes I have granted user all priviledge

Comment: however,specify your `laravel` version

Comment: @Md.Amirozzaman...Laravel version is 5.8